# mongodb any idiom for collapsing 2 upserts into one : create, modifier-to-set-default-values, modifier-to-update-existing-document

Tags: mongodb, race-condition, database, nosql

I want to avoid doing two operations to achieve the following :

1. Find document, update with modifier-1.
2. If document not exist, populate default fields with modifier-2, then update with modifier-1.

it's a common pattern so it should be possible. At the moment I am having to do two upserts.
( feel free to adjust the psuedocode, I am new to the query language).

```
update( {...}, modifier-1, true)

if(upserted) 
{
    // check for race condition, detect if another query from another thread
    // hasn't populated the default values.
    update ( {...,if_a_default_value_does_not_exist}, modifier-2, true)
}
```

I assume that two operations would result in two disk writes, I understand mongodb does asynchronous disk writes. If I can't do this with one operation, is there some sort of mechanism in place that would merge the writes into a single write before writing to journal / disk ? And yes this would make a significant difference in loading my 300 gb data set :D

Answer (score 1):

Hassan,

The asynchronous writes to disk you mentioned are accomplished by writing the changes to memory and then fsync'ing them onto disk periodically in the background, so merging the two operations would likely not impact performance here as much as you would think.

The journal is another matter entirely - it is written separately to disk in an idempotent manner for safety to allow for easier recovery/restoration in case of failure or other similar issues.  You can always start the DB with journaling off, do the import, and then restart with journaling enabled once the bulk update is done if the journal writes are causing you significant issues.

Finally, be careful of the not exists logic in your second modifier - from an indexing perspective a positive operator such as exits is preferred, otherwise indexes may not be used and that will certainly slow down your inserts.

Away from bulk inserts, for single atomic updates you can also explore the use of findAndModify (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) to do the check and subsequent change for you, it's hard to tell based on the description if that would be a good fit because it has its own drawbacks.

Comment: I could remove the not exists actually, as no other thread of control should get an "upserted" state returned.